# Lenovo E15 G3 with Windows 11 extremely slow

Tags: windows, laptop, performance, windows-11, lenovo-laptop

I recently bought a 3rd generation Lenovo Thinkpad E15 (512GB SSD variant) with Windows 11 Pro. It has 16 GB of RAM, and a Ryzen 7 processor.

For several months, Windows Explorer has been extremely slow.  File explorer can take 2 seconds to open after pressing <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>.  While navigating the filesystem, opening folders, and moving up and down the directory tree takes a second per change. It's very sluggish.

Aside from this, there are no other issues, and the rest of the software runs within expectations.

I've run Lenovo diagnostics software to check the hardware, but no issues are reported. I update the BIOS, but there was no change.  I've also updated Windows without effect.

This problem has been going on for a few months without any change for better or worse.

I am tempted to do a factory reset, however, there are a lot of documents, files, and software that I would need to backup and reinstall which would constitute a lot of work that I would prefer to avoid.

Comment: Is this a new machine?  I cannot find it on Lenovo (I use their X machines). Is it running Windows 11 production or insider?. If new, ask Lenovo Support.

Comment: @John, it comes on up the auto-detect as: E15 Gen 3 Laptop (ThinkPad) - Type 20YG. I believe its the production Win 11. I haven't heard about the difference but from a quick search it seems the insider version would leave a watermark on the desktop. It was new in August 2022, and in hindsight I should probably have gotten around to talking with Lenovo then. The three last windows Pcs I bought before this one all had various issues, so I assume I did some half-closing my eye in hopes of it being something that would pass with an update or similar

Comment: The watermark is the Insider watermark. Production does not leave a watermark. So I think this was a Windows 10 machine originally. I have new Lenovo machines (desktop and laptop) and both very fast - both Windows 11 Production

Comment: @John Interesting. How can you think it's a Windows 10 original machine? It wouldn't surprise me though. Just be clear though: there is no desktop watermark present. If it is original win 10, I would assume its possible to install windows 10 without having any driver compatability issues

Comment: Maybe ask Lenovo Support in this case.

Comment: Yeah, I'll give them a call

Comment: Does this also happen when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: @harrymc Thats a good question. I will try and get right back to you

Comment: @harrymc much, much faster in safe mode.

Comment: @BlindSpots Yes, right-clicking, renaming files, creating new folders. It takes about 3 seconds from right-clicking until the dropdown menu appears

Comment: Try [my solution](https://superuser.com/a/1767184/1007040).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that Safe Mode works faster and given that a search through extensions did not reveal the problem, then:

**(a)** Not at all likely a hardware issue and,

**(b)** Try a Windows 11 Repair Install.

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11

Windows 11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Download.
Run the downloaded file  (double click on it).  You will need a USB key as running the download creates a USB Key.
Run Setup on the USB Key. This will launch the Repair.
Proceed normally answering the prompts.
The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything.

**(c)**  If a Keep Everything Repair does not work, then there is either User Profile damage or more serious Operating System damage.

Either way, back everything up and install Windows 11 fresh.

Comment: I ran the tool and did a Windows 11 install, disabling most services through msconfig and partially re-enabled them. The system is much snappier now. I haven't been able to locate a single source of the fault but will continue to probe as I reenable more services

Answer (score 0):

##### Run Nirsoft ShellExView

Nirsoft [ShellExView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html)

> The ShellExView utility displays the details of shell extensions installed on your computer, and allows you to easily disable and enable each shell extension.

Since you don't experience the issue in Safe Mode I suspect it is one of the extensions.

If you disable all the extensions and the problem disappears, you can then systematically re-enable them until one "trips" the problem again.

Comment: I tried this now, but the problem remains after disabling extensions

Comment: Okay.  You'll need to go through the typical approaches and see which if any work.   Given that safe mode eliminates the problem, try a modified startup to see if you can isolate the problem.  eg.g `msconfig` **>** `services` and disable 3rd party services and reboot.  If problem disappears, systematically re-enable until you "trip" the problem"  After that also look at `taskmgr` **>** `Startup apps` and go through the same process.

Answer (score 0):

As booting in Safe Mode fixes the problem, this indicates
that some third-party application or driver is responsible for this
behavior.

I would first try to turn off Windows Defender runtime scanning
(the same if you have installed another such product).
Enable it back after testing.

A tool that can help find out which type of product causes it is
the Windows utility of `msconfig`. In its General tab, you may set
the next boot to "Selective startup" and turn off
system services or startup items.

A tool that allows to disable startup items in a more targeted
way is the free
[Autoruns for Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns).

This utility shows all programs configured to run during system boot or login
in its "Everything" tab, but also sorts out startups according to type
in its other tabs.

You may turn off startup items with a click and return
them later with another click. You may avoid listing Microsoft products by
using the menu *Options > Hide Microsoft Entries*,
*Hide Empty Locations* and *Hide Windows Entries*.

If you can't detect the problematic product by logic alone, the hard way
is to turn off startup entries in bunches, drilling down to
the startup program that causes this behavior.
This will be a painful and long process.

Once the problematic product is identified, it might
have some setting that can avoid the problem, or can be uninstalled.